# Can regular drip coffee grounds be used for pour over coffee and achieve good results?

Tags: drip-brew, pour-over

Can you use regular drip coffee for pour over, and if you do will the coffee taste OK?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, it'll be fine.

Drip brewing and pour-over coffee are essentially the same process:  Pour hot water over ground coffee to extract flavor compounds, then let the infused hot water solution drip through a filter into a serving vessel.  As far as the final product is concerned, it doesn't especially matter if this happens in a machine that dispenses the hot water automatically (drip brewing), or if you pour the water yourself by hand.

The only reason coffee grounds might be suitable for one but not the other would be if you use different filters for drip brewing and pourovers.  For instance, if you have a drip coffee machine that takes paper filters, but a standalone metal mesh filter that you use for pourovers, you would want to use slightly coarser coffee grounds for the latter.  Even in this case, though, the worst possible outcome would be that your coffee might be a little cloudy or gritty, just like if your grounds were slightly too fine (because that's exactly what's happened).